# Provide Fully Qualified Table.Column Name Headers in SQL Server 2014 Query Results

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to cause SQL Server Management Studio to return query results where the source table names are displayed as prefixes next to each resulting data column name? I'm just manually forming and executing lots of different queries on the fly, queries that bind multiple tables with similarly named columns. I'm doing this to try to learn the ins and outs of an extremely large, undocumented database that has had no relationships established between tables. For instance, table A may have a column named X, but a related table B also has a column named X. I'm finding these similarities as I go, indicating potential relationships between tables. However, when there are several instances of duplicate column names across several large tables I'm trying to bind, it's hard to discern in the query result set whether I'm looking at the X column that comes from table A as opposed to B. I know that I could use the AS keyword and individually relabel my desired columns right in the SELECT clause. And that might be my only recourse if you say so. However, I want to more quickly form queries while I study this database without necessarily making my queries very elaborate right now. It would be great if the SQL Server result sets could have more clearly labeled column headers of the form table.column, for example: A.X, B.X, etc. That would suffice. How can I make SQL Server 2014 display such qualified column headers?

Comment: You can add your own alias, like SELECT c.A, c.B, t.A AS [T.A] FROM c INNER JOIN t blah blah...  just use the "AS [new column name]" syntax. It's a manual thing, not automatic. I know of no way to make SSMS do it automatically for you.

Comment: I am using aliases. That, I am doing. Yet they won't show up as header column names either.

Comment: Thats just something that SQL - Server doesn't do, unfortunately. What I've usually done is (a) get a list of the columns from SSMS GUI or system views, then (b) use a text editor with good regex capability to generate aliases that identify the table from which a column comes, using a pattern like tablea_columna ...

Comment: I use column aliases to set header column names all the time. What do you mean they aren't showing up for you? If you say SELECT foo AS [MyColumnName] the header is "MyColumnName" just as specified. I've never seen this not work, so clearly I'm not understanding what you're saying, or what you're trying. Can you provide an example in your question? Including Expected and Actual output?

Comment: Sorry, I meant table aliases, not column aliases. I am using table aliases alright. Just not column aliases. As I originally stated in the question, I know I can create my own column aliases using the AS keyword but I'm just trying to quickly run through lots of different combinations of queries without elaborating them too much with column aliases. What I want is SQL Server to more clearly delineate what table a column in my result set came from (without me manually giving each duplicate column name an alias).

Comment: Being as [incredibly] there doesn't appear to be a simple, practical solution for this, I submitted a product suggestion to Microsoft (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3140012).

Answer (score 0):

While I believe that there's no way for SSMS to do what you want in a bonafide automated fashion, there's a way to do so with a smart script, which can build your query without too much frustration. I had the need to do something similar in the past, and I used a variant of the following:

```
select 
    quotename(tab.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(col.name)  + ' AS ' + quotename(tab.name + '.' + col.name) 
from sys.columns col
inner join sys.tables tab on col.object_id = tab.object_id
where tab.name = '<enter table name here>'
```

This will spit out all fields, properly formatted, quoted, and aliased. With a little tweaking, you should be able to add the rest of your query to this script.

Comment: If I had more time or something more formal to build I'd use your idea. But I'm really just trying to quickly examine the database and determine which columns make sense to bind without a lot of extra programming or manual steps.